# How to post a list of files using Curl

Tags: python, post, curl, flask, request

I need to curl multiple files to a website as a list, but I'm having trouble doing so.

I've tried:

```
curl -F name=fn1 -F filedata=@fn1.jpg -F name=fn2 -F filedata=@fn2.jpg
```

But that didn't work, so I tried:

```
curl -F "files[]=@fn1.jpg&files[]=fn2.jpg"
```

But that also didn't work.

I'm trying to get the files on the server side using the python request lib, so something like:

```
files = request.files.getlist('files[]')
```

But this call always fails, how do I post a list of files using curl?

Comment: Is this question about Python?

Comment: I'm open to the possbility that I'm trying to access the data the wrong way in my flask-python-app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out, the syntax is this :

`curl -F files=@$WALLPAPERS/0FYIE5G.jpg \
-F files=@$WALLPAPERS/3GVmZmQ.png http://example.com/upload`

And on the receiving end :

`files = request.files.getlist('files')`

Pretty simple actually.